# Can you overcome vb.net from HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri and HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl using different case symbols?

Tags: vb.net, request, symbols

The code below throws a server error:

```
Option Compare Text

Dim strAppURL As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl))
```

*System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Length cannot be less than zero.*

because:

> HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri =

```
"http://localhost:22222/Dev/Canvas.aspx?&act=ccis&filn=002+(Ene+D%C4%83nu%C5%A3).png"
```

and

> HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl =

```
"/Dev/Canvas.aspx?&act=ccis&filn=002+(Ene+D%c4%83nu%c5%a3).png"
```

Observe the symbols are different: **%C4%83** vs. **%c4%83** and **%C5%A3** vs. **%c5%a3**

Just in case this issue was encountered before, I would welcome some help in handling it outside the code (other than using ToUpper() or ToLower() methods). I would prefer an application level directive. Thank you.

Comment: `IndexOf` has a `StringComparison` parameter, simply set it to ignore case

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is a lot simpler that my ToLower() method. I used to code a lot in VB 6 and VBA and using StrComp(str1, str2, vbTextCompare/vbBinaryCompare)  was a bit similar. However, since the two belong to the same object (HttpContext.Current.Request) I had hopped that using one single application directive would fix the problem. I do not understand why the difference exists to begin with... A bug, oversight, special purpose?!?!... Thank you again.